# Solve the equation $|x-7|-3|2x+1|=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This equation is very unfamiliar with me, I never seen things like that because I always solved equations of the form $|\text{something}|=\text{things}$ but never seen equations that look like $|\text{something}|=|\text{things}|$. So if I learn how to solve it I will be able to solve questions that looks like it. Thank you;

Comment: Just look at $|\text{things}|$ as $things$ and you'll reduce the problem to something you know.

Comment: You mean reduce $|x-7|-3|2x+1|=0$ to $x-7-3(2x+1)=0$ ?

Comment: No. Let $y=|2x+1|$. Your equation is equivalent to $|x-7|=3y$. Now forget what $y$ is (for now) and solve $|x-7|=3y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can turn it into form

$$\left|\dfrac{x-7}{2x+1}\right | = 3$$

(assuming $2x + 1 \neq 0$).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method would be to let $f(x)=|x-7|-3|2x+1|$ and then writing $f(x)$ without the absolute value using $3$ different cases. Then solving the equation $f(x)=0$ using what we did earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the cases $x<-\frac12,-\frac12\le x<7,x\ge 7$.

Case I: $x<-\frac12$

$7-x-3(-2x-1)=0$

$7-x+6x+3=0$

$5x+10=0$

$x=-2$

Case II: $-\frac12\le x<7$

$7-x-3(2x+1)=0$

$7-x-6x-3=0$

$4-7x=0$

$x=\frac47$

Case III: $x\ge 7$

$x-7-3(2x+1)=0$

$x-7-6x-3=0$

$-5x-10=0$

$x=-2$

Hence there is no solution for $x$.

Therefore, $x=-2$ or $x=\frac47$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x-7 = \pm3(2x+1)
$$

So choose "$+$" and find the solutions, and then choose "$-$" and find the solutions.

Comment: @amWhy : Correct.  The "y" key is close to the "7" key.

Comment: Don't I know how proximity of keys leads to typos! (Also, shift vs. non-shift typos: e.g. $4 \sim \$$

Comment: @amWhy : The other source of typos is that when the keys for two adjacent letters are pressed with fingers different hands, then they get interchanged.

Comment: I didn't know that! (Just tested it, and you're right!) Maybe it helps explain how I manage to generate typos in words like "heihgt".

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this kind of equation is to notice that any solution to that equation is a solution to one of
$$
\frac{x-7}{2x+1}=\pm3
$$
then solve each equation and toss answers that don't fit.
$$
\frac{x-7}{2x+1}=3\implies x=-2
$$
and
$$
\frac{x-7}{2x+1}=-3\implies x=\frac47
$$
Both of these fit the original equation and are therefore all of the solutions.

Note that if $2x+1=0$ we have $x-7=-\frac{15}{2}$ so the equation is not satisfied if the denominator is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

$x-7=3(2x+1)$ or $x-7=-3(2x+1)$

if $x-7=3(2x+1)$, then $x=-2$.

if $x-7=-3(2x+1)$, then $x=-\frac{10}7$. drop it

Comment: x= 4/7 not -10/7

Answer (score 0):

|x-7|=|6x+3|
then either 
x-7=6x+3

or 
x-7=-6x-3
solve these two equations.

Answer (score 0):

$|x-7|-3|2x+1|=0\qquad$ iff $\qquad|x-7|=3|2x+1|\qquad$ iff $\qquad|x-7|^2=3^2|2x+1|^2$

iff $\qquad(x-7)^2=3^2(2x+1)^2\qquad$ iff $\qquad\cdots$

Answer (score 0):

### $$ |x-7|-3|2x+1|=0 $$

Here's a trick that avoids cases.

\begin{align}
   |x-7|-3|2x+1| &= 0 \\
   |x-7| &= 3|2x+1| \\
   (|x-7|)^2 &= 9(|2x+1|)^2 \\
   x^2-14x + 49 &= 36x^2 +36x + 9 \\
   35x^2+50x-40 &= 0 \\
   7x^2+10x - 8 &= 0 \\
   (7x - 4)(x + 2) &= 0 \\
   x &\in \left\{ \dfrac 47, -2  \right\}
\end{align}